# How can I reenable the back button in Evince on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10, evince

I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 and my evince is not showing Back/Forward history navigation buttons. Various comments on the internet claim that one can enable them by editing the tool bar, but none of the described methods worked on Ubuntu 19.10.

Hot keys Alt-P/N still work, but ....